# Units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

How would one compute the units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]2]$? According to one source, it can be shown that the fundamental units are $1 + \sqrt[4]2$ and $1 + \sqrt{2}$, but it does not specify the proof of this.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty here... but doesn't Dirichlet's unit theorem tell you that there are 3 fundamental units, as there are $4$ complex embeddings?

Comment: @Mathmo123 There's $2$ complex and $2$ real embeddings, $\sqrt[4]{2} \mapsto \pm \sqrt[4]{2}$ being the real ones, so $2+1-1 = 2$ fundamental units.

Comment: So I am rusty.... but in which case that means that given that we know there are only 2 fundamental units, it suffices to show that the ones in the question are them... which shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @Mathmo123 I agree with the method, but I'm not sure how you would go about that! I know tricks for a single fundamental unit (show that is is some sense the smallest) but I don't really know how to translate that into multiple fundamentals. Perhaps the $\log$ map from $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{r+s}$ might be of use? Pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument to at least prove that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is not the power of any unit
in $\mathbb Z[2^{1/4}].$

Suppose that there were a unit $u \in \mathbb Z[2^{1/4}]$ for which $u^2 = 1+\sqrt{2}$.  Since $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a fundamental unit of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}],$
we see that $u \not\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, and so
$\mathbb Q(2^{1/4}) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})(u^{1/2}).$

But a local calculation at $2$ will show that the power of $2$ dividing the discriminant of $\mathbb Z_2[2^{1/4}]$ is greater than that dividing the
discriminant of $\mathbb Z_2[\sqrt{2},u^{1/2}]$ for any unit $u \in \mathbb Z_2[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$.

Thus the claimed equality can't hold, and so $u$ must not exist.